# Why Google Chrome and Firefox share bookmarks on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, google-chrome

I've been having this problem for a while now. My wife uses Firefox and I use Google Chrome, but somehow the bookmarks on Google Chrome shows on Firefox and the Hotmail session is shared between Google Chrome and Firefox, I log in on Hotmail in Google Chrome and Firefox use the same session.

Why that happens?

How could I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Ubuntu the most straightforward solution is to [add a new user account](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-help/user-add.html) that will hold the settings for one of you while the other uses the settings in the existing account.